# How to change colour gradient in geom_contour_filled()

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I am trying to change the colour gradient in geom_contour_filled

Is there a way to specify a colour gradient that will automatically generate the number of colours to match the levels generated by geom_contour_filled()?

Example:

```
v <- ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions, z = density))
v + geom_contour_filled()
```

This uses the standard viridis palette (dark blue to yellow).

Now try to change the palette:

```
v + geom_contour_filled() +
  scale_fill_binned(type = colorRampPalette(c("grey20", "orange")))

v + geom_contour_filled() +
  scale_fill_steps(low = "grey20", high = "orange")

v + geom_contour_filled() +
  scale_fill_stepsn(colors = colorRampPalette(c("grey20", "orange"))(8))
```

None of these work.

This works, except one has to specify the number of colours manually which is inconvenient.

```
v + geom_contour_filled() +
  scale_fill_discrete(type = colorRampPalette(c("grey20", "orange"))(8))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the low-level function `discrete_scale`, which has a `palette` argument. This accepts a palette function, such as that produced by `colorRampPalette`. Otherwise you need only specify the aesthetic you want to map (`fill`) and give it any name you like in the second argument.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions, z = density)) +
  geom_contour_filled(color = 'gray20', linewidth = 0.2) +
  discrete_scale('fill', 'myscale', colorRampPalette(c("grey20", "orange"))) +
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE)
```

[image]

If you wanted to use `scale_fill_steps`, you would need fill to be mapped to a continuous variable. You could do this with `fill = after_stat(level_mid)`

```r
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions, z = density)) +
  geom_contour_filled(color = 'gray20', linewidth = 0.2,
                      aes(fill = after_stat(level_mid))) +
  scale_fill_steps("level", low = "gray20", high = "orange", n.breaks = 8) +
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm surprised that scale_fill_binned and scale_fill_steps don't work, and hadn't even heard of discrete_scale.

Comment: @DanB It is possible to use `scale_fill_steps`, but you need to give it a numeric variable. By default, the fill scale is mapped to `after_stat(level)`, which is an ordered factor, but if you change it to `after_stat(level_mid)` then you get a numeric value you can use - see my update

Comment: Thank you @Allan. To avoid having to specify the number of breaks, using scale_fill_gradient(low = "grey20", high ="orange") works well